# How can I get a list of all folders and files opened in last month?

Tags: filesystem

How can I get a list of all folders and files I opened in the last month? Preferably in the command line, with the date included. I am newbie on linux by the way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Files:

```
find -type f -mtime -31
```

Folders:

```
find -type d -mtime -31
```

It will search from the directory where you typed it.

Comment: Now you forget about the folders :)
if it's necessary folders can be added by a second find:
find -type f -mtime -31 ; find -type d -mtime -31

Comment: @Requist wow I soooo mis-read the question :X

Comment: I don't want to see "modified" files, I want to see "opened" (or "accessed" using linux terminology) files. So, I guess the best is to use "atime" option. The commands work fine for files, but for folders there are some odd results. For example, typing "find -type d -amin -60" gives me the files opened in the last hour. But if I type "find -type d -amin -60", there are no results, despite I obviously accessed the folders where the files were.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using command line, you have used a command to open the file (like vi). So you can get all the commands you used using the command:

**$history**

This command show all the commands that the user used.

Comment: That was not the question, it was about files and folders.